# Insert a character into parser combinator character stream in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators, uu-parsinglib

This question is related to both `Parsec` and `uu-parsinglib`. When we write parser combinators, they process characters streams from compiler. Is it somehow possible to parse a character and put it back (or return another character back) to the input stream?

I want for example to parse input "test + 5", parse the `t`, `e`, `s`, `t` and after recognition of `test` pattern, put for example `v` character back into the character stream, so while continuating the parsing process we are matching against `v + 5`

I do not want to use this in any particular case for now - I want to deeply learn the possibilities.

Comment: It is certainly possible with Parsec as you can use the `getInput` and `setInput` functions.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with Parsec, but it certainly increases the complexity of the parser and makes debugging more difficult. A common use for it is to implement preprocessors for programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible with these parsers directly, but in general you can accomplish it by combining parsers with some streaming that allows injecting leftovers.

For example, using [attoparsec-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec-conduit/1.0.1.2/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Attoparsec.html) you can turn a parser into a conduit using

```
sinkParser :: (AttoparsecInput a, MonadThrow m)
           => Parser a b -> Consumer a m b
```

where `Consumer` is a special kind of conduit that doesn't produce any output, only receives input and returns a final value.

Since conduits support leftovers, you can create a helper method that converts a parser that optionally returns a value to be pushed into the stream into a conduit:

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Types
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Attoparsec
import Data.Functor

reinject :: (AttoparsecInput a, MonadThrow m)
    => Parser a (Maybe a, b) -> Consumer a m b
reinject p = do
    (lo, r) <- sinkParser p
    maybe (return ()) leftover lo
    return r
```

Then you convert standard parsers to conduits using `sinkParser` and these special parsers using `reinject`, and then combine conduits instead of parsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to archive this is to build a multi-layered parser. Think of a lexer + parser combination. This is a clean approach to this problem.

You have to separate the two kind of parsing. The search-and-replace parsing goes to the first parser and the build-the-AST parsing to the second. Or you can create an intermediate token representation.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

parserLvl1 :: Parser String
parserLvl1 = many (try (string "test" >> return 'v') <|> anyChar)

parserLvl2 :: Parser Plus
parserLvl2 = do text1 <- many (noneOf "+")
                char '+'
                text2 <- many (noneOf "+")
                return $ Plus text1 text2

data Plus = Plus String String
  deriving Show

wholeParse :: String -> Either ParseError Plus
wholeParse source = do res1 <- parse parserLvl1 "lvl1" source
                       res2 <- parse parserLvl2 "lvl2" res1
                       return res2
```

Now you can parse your example. `wholeParse "test+5"` results in `Right (Plus "v" "5")`.

Possible variations:

- Create a class and an instance for combining wrapped parser stages. (Possibly carrying parser state.)
- Create an intermediate representation, a stream of tokens

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done in uu-parsinglib using the pSwitch function. But the question is why you want to do so? Because the v is missing from the input? In that case uu-parsinglib will perform error correction automatically so you do not need something like this. Otherwise you can write

```
pSwitch :: (st1 -> (st2, st2 -> st1)) -> P st2 a -> P st1 a
pInsert_v = pSwitch (\st1 -> (prepend v st2, id) (pSucceed ())
```

It depends on your actual state type how the v is actually added, so you will have to define the function

```
prepend
```

yourself. I do not know e.g. how such an insertion would influence the current position in the file etc.

Doaitse Swierstra